# Given two Linked Lists, find the index where one list is sublist of another

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

Recently I took part in a java coding challenge in my college and was asked this problem which I found difficult to implement.

Problem was to implement a method `detect` that given two `LinkedList`, return the index where second list is sublist of first.

```
detect((1,2,3),(2,3)) should return 1
```

The node structure to the list was

```
LinkedListNode {
   String val;
   LinkedListNode *next;
}
```

and the method signature

```
static int detect(LinkedListNode list, LinkedListNode sublist)
```

What would be the basic algorithm to approach this problem. I am a newbie to data structures.

Comment: Are those lists sorted?

Comment: Should `detect((1,2,3,4),(2,3))` also return 1?

Comment: @Manu : yes. It should

Comment: @PhamTrung: Not necessarily.

Comment: This looks like a DFS.

Comment: @roger_that: Can you please check if my algorithm works for you?

Comment: The same ideas as for string search should apply.

Answer (score 4):

I believe [Collections.indexOfSubList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#indexOfSubList%28java.util.List,%20java.util.List%29) implements this. You can look at it's implementation.
Basically:

```
    ListIterator<?> si = source.listIterator();
    nextCand:
        for (int candidate = 0; candidate <= maxCandidate; candidate++) {
            ListIterator<?> ti = target.listIterator();
            for (int i=0; i<targetSize; i++) {
                if (!eq(ti.next(), si.next())) {
                    // Back up source iterator to next candidate
                    for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
                        si.previous();
                    continue nextCand;
                }
            }
            return candidate;
        }
```

Comment: when i use Collections.indexOfSubList over the parameter list in method signature, I am getting runtime error saying it does not applies to node type

Comment: That's because your LinkedListNode does not implement List  => either make it implement List or copy paste the above algorithm and adapt it to your code !
Don't downvote an answer just because it shows you the way without giving you the complete solution

Comment: Just for your information, I have not down voted your answer.

Comment: @roger_that My misunderstanding on the downvoting. I do not know who downvoted it and thought it came from you. Sorry. Just hope the JDK's algo will help you find your's

Comment: Is it actually the best run time? If I'm not mistaken, it will be at worse O(N*M), N being the size of source, M being the size of target.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to traverse the second list and for every index in this list check for equality in first list for consecutive elements. The following algorithm will work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        list1.add(1);
        list1.add(2);
        list1.add(3);
        list1.add(4);
        list1.add(5);
        list1.add(6);
        List<Integer> list2 = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        list2.add(2);
        list2.add(3);


        boolean contains = true;
        int currIndex = 0;
        int i = 0,j = 0;
        for(;j<list2.size();j++) {
            int e2 = list2.get(j);
            for(i=currIndex;i<list1.size();i++) {
                if(e2 == list1.get(i)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(i == list1.size()) {
                contains = false;
                break;
            }
            currIndex++;
            if( contains && (currIndex == list2.size()) ) {
                System.out.println("Index is: " + (i-j));
            }
        }
    }
```

This prints `Index is: 1` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int detect(LinkedListNode list, LinkedListNode sublist) {
        int counter = 0;
        int index = -1;
        LinkedListNode sub = sublist;

        do {
            if (list.val == sub.val) {
                if (index == -1)
                    index = counter;
                if (sub.next != null) {
                    sub = sub.next;
                    if (sub.next == null) {
                        return index;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                index = -1;
                sub = sublist;
            }
            list = list.next;
            counter++;

        } while (list.next != null);

        return index;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, the value is String here :-

```
static int find(LinkedListNode list, LinkedListNode sublist) {
    String listString = convertLinkedListToString(list);
    String sublistString = convertLinkedListToString(sublist);
    return listString.indexOf(sublistString);
}

private static String convertLinkedListToString(LinkedListNode list) {
    String listAsString = "";
    while(list != null) {
        listAsString = listAsString + list.val;
        list = list.next;
    }
    return listAsString;
}
```